# Change $null behavior to print out?

Tags: powershell

Take the following snippet

```
'a',$null,'b'
```

This is the result

```
a
b
```

Is there a way to change this default?  So that null is actually treated in output as *something*.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to change that behaviour, but as a workaround you can do this:

```
[string[]]('a',$null,'b')
```

to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This will turn the $null into a blank string:

```
'a',$null,'b' | % { "$_" }
```

Or you could transform the `$null` into some arbitrary string such as `'[null]'`:

```
'a',$null,'b' | % { if ($_ -ne $null) {$_} else {'[null]'} }
```